# How can I apply a custom function that adds new columns to a dataframe to a subset of existing columns?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lapply

I am working with a large dataset where much of the data was entered twice. This means that many of the variables are represented by pairs of columns: `column.1` with the data entered by one person, and `column.2` where the same data was entered by a different person. I want to create a "master" column called simply `column` that first draws from `column.1` and then, if `column.1` is `NA`, draws from `column.2`.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do with made-up data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(name = c("Sarah","Ella","Carmen","Dinah","Billie"),
                     cheese.1 = c(1,4,NA,6,NA),
                     cheese.2 = c(1,4,3,5,NA),
                     milk.1 = c(NA,2,0,4,NA),
                     milk.2 = c(1,2,1,4,2),
                     tofu.1 = c("yum","yum",NA,"gross", NA),
                     tofu.2 = c("gross", "yum", "yum", NA, "gross"))
```

For example, the code below shows an example of what I want to do for a single pair of columns.

```
mydata %>% mutate(cheese = ifelse(is.na(cheese.1), cheese.2, cheese.1))

#OUTPUT:

    name cheese.1 cheese.2 milk.1 milk.2 tofu.1 tofu.2 cheese
1  Sarah        1        1     NA      1    yum  gross      1
2   Ella        4        4      2      2    yum    yum      4
3 Carmen       NA        3      0      1   <NA>    yum      3
4  Dinah        6        5      4      4  gross   <NA>      6
5 Billie       NA       NA     NA      2   <NA>  gross     NA
```

However, I want to automate the process rather than doing each manually. Below is my attempt at automating the process, using a list (`col.list`) of the column pairs for which I want to create new "master" columns:

```
col.list = c("cheese","milk","tofu")

lapply(col.list, FUN = function(x) {
  v <- as.name({{x}})
  v.1 <- as.name(paste0({{x}}, ".1"))
  v.2 <- as.name(paste0(({{x}}), ".2"))
  mydata %>% mutate(v = ifelse(is.na({{v.1}}), {{v.2}}, {{v.1}}))
})

#OUTPUT:

[[1]]
    name cheese.1 cheese.2 milk.1 milk.2 tofu.1 tofu.2  v
1  Sarah        1        1     NA      1    yum  gross  1
2   Ella        4        4      2      2    yum    yum  4
3 Carmen       NA        3      0      1   <NA>    yum  3
4  Dinah        6        5      4      4  gross   <NA>  6
5 Billie       NA       NA     NA      2   <NA>  gross NA

[[2]]
    name cheese.1 cheese.2 milk.1 milk.2 tofu.1 tofu.2 v
1  Sarah        1        1     NA      1    yum  gross 1
2   Ella        4        4      2      2    yum    yum 2
3 Carmen       NA        3      0      1   <NA>    yum 0
4  Dinah        6        5      4      4  gross   <NA> 4
5 Billie       NA       NA     NA      2   <NA>  gross 2

[[3]]
    name cheese.1 cheese.2 milk.1 milk.2 tofu.1 tofu.2     v
1  Sarah        1        1     NA      1    yum  gross   yum
2   Ella        4        4      2      2    yum    yum   yum
3 Carmen       NA        3      0      1   <NA>    yum   yum
4  Dinah        6        5      4      4  gross   <NA> gross
5 Billie       NA       NA     NA      2   <NA>  gross gross
```

The problems with this attempt are:

1. the new columns are not correctly named (they should be named `cheese`, `milk` and `tofu` rather than all be called `v`)
2. the new columns are not added to the original data frame. What I want is for the program to add a series of new "master" columns to my dataframe (one new column for each pair of columns identified in `col.list`).

Comment: I'm interested in a solution using `coalesce` which I couldn't use with "dynamic" column names. Perhaps someone reading this could give some insights?

Comment: @Martin Gal, please have a look at my solution. It‘s not with dynamic column names, but at least with `coalesce`.

Comment: @MartinGal I added an option using `exec` and `coalesce`. It has dynamic names, but only with the help of `str_glue()`.

Answer (score 9):

(1) You have to wrap `v` into the curly-curly operator and use `:=`:

```r
library(dplyr)

col.list <- c("cheese","milk","tofu")

lapply(col.list, FUN = function(x) {
  v <- as.name({{x}})
  v.1 <- as.name(paste0({{x}}, ".1"))
  v.2 <- as.name(paste0(({{x}}), ".2"))
  mydata %>% mutate({{ v }} = ifelse(is.na({{v.1}}), {{v.2}}, {{v.1}}))
})
```

returns

```r
[[1]]
    name cheese.1 cheese.2 milk.1 milk.2 tofu.1 tofu.2 cheese
1  Sarah        1        1     NA      1    yum  gross      1
2   Ella        4        4      2      2    yum    yum      4
3 Carmen       NA        3      0      1   <NA>    yum      3
4  Dinah        6        5      4      4  gross   <NA>      6
5 Billie       NA       NA     NA      2   <NA>  gross     NA

[...]
```

which is one step closer to your desired output.

(2) But to get your desired output, I suggest using `purrr`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

col.list %>% 
  map(~mydata %>% 
        select(name, starts_with(.x)) %>% 
        mutate({{ .x }} := ifelse(
          is.na(!!sym(paste0(.x, ".1"))), 
          !!sym(paste0(.x, ".2")), 
          !!sym(paste0(.x, ".1"))
          )
        )
  ) %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = "name")
```

This returns

```r
    name cheese.1 cheese.2 cheese milk.1 milk.2 milk tofu.1 tofu.2  tofu
1  Sarah        1        1      1     NA      1    1    yum  gross   yum
2   Ella        4        4      4      2      2    2    yum    yum   yum
3 Carmen       NA        3      3      0      1    0   <NA>    yum   yum
4  Dinah        6        5      6      4      4    4  gross   <NA> gross
5 Billie       NA       NA     NA     NA      2    2   <NA>  gross gross
```

Comment: Great answer. I tried to find an rlang answer but eventually gave up.

Comment: @GuedesBF Your answer is far more elegant and (I guess) faster.

Comment: Up for the challenge as always my friend :)

Comment: I only have one suggestion because long ago Anil told me and I tried it ever since. I would always prefer to not hard-code the solution because we don't know have many of these might be in the real data set.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a pretty simple and dynamic option. Since it uses [tidyselect](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html), if there are more than just two columns (eg `cheese.1`, `cheese.2`, *and* `cheese.3`) this will still work. This will also work if the column groups are unbalanced (eg 3 cheese columns, but only 2 milk columns):

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

col.list <- c("cheese","milk","tofu")

express <- map(set_names(col.list), ~ 
                 str_glue("coalesce(!!!across(starts_with(\"{.x}\")))") %>% 
                 parse_expr())

mydata %>%
  mutate(!!! express, .keep = "unused")
```

**Output**

The other columns were removed by `.keep = "unused"`. If you want to keep all the columns then delete that argument.

```
    name cheese milk  tofu
1  Sarah      1    1   yum
2   Ella      4    2   yum
3 Carmen      3    0   yum
4  Dinah      6    4 gross
5 Billie     NA    2 gross
```

**How it works**

1. The use of `map` and `set_names` is important because this creates a named list, which is important for the big-bang `!!!` operator later. `map` creates a *named* list of expressions.
2. The use of `across` and `coalesce` allows the dynamic tidy-selection of columns.
3. The `!!!` operator force-splices the list of objects and the names for the columns are from the list names set up using `map` and `set_names`.

Comment: I like using `glue` package here :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way of doing this amid all the great answers you got:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

col.list %>%
  reduce(~ .x %>% 
           bind_cols(mydata %>% 
                       select(starts_with(.y)) %>%
                       mutate(!!gsub("(\\D+)\\.\\d+", "\\1", .y) := invoke(coalesce, cur_data()))), 
         .init = NULL)

  cheese.1 cheese.2 cheese milk.1 milk.2 milk tofu.1 tofu.2  tofu
1        1        1      1     NA      1    1    yum  gross   yum
2        4        4      4      2      2    2    yum    yum   yum
3       NA        3      3      0      1    0   <NA>    yum   yum
4        6        5      6      4      4    4  gross   <NA> gross
5       NA       NA     NA     NA      2    2   <NA>  gross gross
```

Comment: I thought, `:=` and `!!` are exported from `rlang` into `dplyr`. ;-)

Comment: Yes Martin you are right. I will edit the description :)

Comment: FYI, `invoke` is soft-depreciated in favor of `exec`.

Comment: @LMc Yes exactly, I went a bit old school here :) Thanks for the upvote, I already did yours.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way I would do it. First convert to long format then reshape back to wide format but having only 2 value columns `1` and `2`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata <- data.frame(name = c("Sarah","Ella","Carmen","Dinah","Billie"),
                     cheese.1 = c(1,4,NA,6,NA),
                     cheese.2 = c(1,4,3,5,NA),
                     milk.1 = c(NA,2,0,4,NA),
                     milk.2 = c(1,2,1,4,2),
                     tofu.1 = c("yum","yum",NA,"gross", NA),
                     tofu.2 = c("gross", "yum", "yum", NA, "gross"))
mydata_long <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.character)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-name,
               names_to = c("food", "nr"),
               names_sep = "\\.")
mydata_long
#> # A tibble: 30 x 4
#>    name  food   nr    value
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#>  1 Sarah cheese 1     1    
#>  2 Sarah cheese 2     1    
#>  3 Sarah milk   1     <NA> 
#>  4 Sarah milk   2     1    
#>  5 Sarah tofu   1     yum  
#>  6 Sarah tofu   2     gross
#>  7 Ella  cheese 1     4    
#>  8 Ella  cheese 2     4    
#>  9 Ella  milk   1     2    
#> 10 Ella  milk   2     2    
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

Apply `ifelse()` function after transforming back to different wide format

```
mydata_wide <- mydata_long %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = nr,
              values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(final_val = ifelse(is.na(`1`), `2`, `1`)) %>% 
  arrange(food)
mydata_wide
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#>    name   food   `1`   `2`   final_val
#>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>    
#>  1 Sarah  cheese 1     1     1        
#>  2 Ella   cheese 4     4     4        
#>  3 Carmen cheese <NA>  3     3        
#>  4 Dinah  cheese 6     5     6        
#>  5 Billie cheese <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     
#>  6 Sarah  milk   <NA>  1     1        
#>  7 Ella   milk   2     2     2        
#>  8 Carmen milk   0     1     0        
#>  9 Dinah  milk   4     4     4        
#> 10 Billie milk   <NA>  2     2        
#> 11 Sarah  tofu   yum   gross yum      
#> 12 Ella   tofu   yum   yum   yum      
#> 13 Carmen tofu   <NA>  yum   yum      
#> 14 Dinah  tofu   gross <NA>  gross    
#> 15 Billie tofu   <NA>  gross gross
```

```
mydata_wide2 <- mydata_wide %>% 
  pivot_wider(-c(`1`, `2`),
              names_from = food,
              values_from = final_val) 
mydata_wide2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   name   cheese milk  tofu 
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Sarah  1      1     yum  
#> 2 Ella   4      2     yum  
#> 3 Carmen 3      0     yum  
#> 4 Dinah  6      4     gross
#> 5 Billie <NA>   2     gross
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I would use `purrr::map_dfc` and `coalesce` here. Looks pretty straightforward.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mydata %>% mutate(map2_dfc(select(., ends_with('1')),
                           select(., ends_with('2')),
                           ~coalesce(.x, .y)))%>%
  select(-ends_with('2'))%>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, '\\.\\d+$'))

    name cheese milk  tofu
1  Sarah      1    1   yum
2   Ella      4    2   yum
3 Carmen      3    0   yum
4  Dinah      6    4 gross
5 Billie     NA    2 gross
```

Comment: Great answer my friend :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can achieve your task:

1. define your pairs (in case you have hundreds of columns, this could be automated.
2. use `imap_dfc` to apply `coalesce` do the defined pairs
3. bind to original dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

pairs <- list(cheese = c(2, 3), milk = c(4, 5), tofu = c(6, 7))

imap_dfc(pairs, ~mydata[, .x] %>% transmute(!!.y := coalesce(!!!syms(names(mydata)[.x])))) %>% 
  bind_cols(mydata)
```

```
  cheese milk  tofu   name cheese.1 cheese.2 milk.1 milk.2 tofu.1 tofu.2
1      1    1   yum  Sarah        1        1     NA      1    yum  gross
2      4    2   yum   Ella        4        4      2      2    yum    yum
3      3    0   yum Carmen       NA        3      0      1   <NA>    yum
4      6    4 gross  Dinah        6        5      4      4  gross   <NA>
5     NA    2 gross Billie       NA       NA     NA      2   <NA>  gross
```

Comment: Lot's of nice ways to solve this one.

Comment: In this case your answer is best. And I think Guedes already answered. So this time you can relax and enjoy!

Comment: This is also great my friend:)

Answer (score 1):

Another tidyverse option. Advantage here is that it keeps the original data type and doesn‘t convert everything to character values.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -name,
               names_pattern = '(.*)(\\..)',
               names_to = c('.value', 'number')) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(across(-number, ~if_else(is.na(.[1]), .[2], .[1]))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(number == '.1') %>%
  select(-number)
```

Which gives

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  name   cheese  milk tofu 
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 Sarah       1     1 yum  
2 Ella        4     2 yum  
3 Carmen      3     0 yum  
4 Dinah       6     4 gross
5 Billie     NA     2 gross
```

Alternative solution with `coalesce`:

```
mydata %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -name,
               names_pattern = '(.*)(\\..)',
               names_to = c('.value', 'number')) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(across(-number, ~coalesce(.[1], .[2]))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(number == '.1') %>%
  select(-number)
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of something like this first but wanted some dynamic columns in the coalesce function. I guess @GuedesBF showed a proper solution for that one. :-)